# Count the number of items derived from split without putting into an array

Tags: perl, while-loop, split, count, bioinformatics

I am looking to spare the use of an array for memory's sake, but still get the number of items derived from the split function for each pass of a while loop.
The ultimate goal is to filter the output files according to the number of their sequences, which could either be deduced by the number of rows the file has, or the number of carrots that appear, or the number of line breaks, etc. 
Below is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings; 
    use strict; 
    use diagnostics; 

    open(INFILE, "<", "Clustered_Barcodes.txt") or die $!;

    my %hash = ( 
            "TTTATGC" => "TATAGCGCTTTATGCTAGCTAGC",
            "TTTATGG" => "TAGCTAGCTTTATGGGCTAGCTA",
            "TTTATCC" => "GCTAGCTATTTATCCGCTAGCTA",
            "TTTATCG" => "AGTCATGCTTTATCGCGATCGAT",
            "TTTATAA" => "TAGCTAGCTTTATAATAGCTAGC",
            "TTTATAA" => "ATCGATCGTTTATAACGATCGAT",
            "TTTATAT" => "TCGATCGATTTATATTAGCTAGC",
            "TTTATAT" => "TAGCTAGCTTTATATGCTAGCTA",
            "TTTATTA" => "GCTAGCTATTTATTATAGCTAGC",
            "CTTGTAA" => "ATCGATCGCTTGTAACGATTAGC",
    );

    while(my $line = <INFILE>){ 
            chomp $line; 
            open my $out, '>', "Clustered_Barcode_$..txt" or die $!;
            foreach my $sequence (split /\t/, $line){
                    if (exists $hash{$sequence}){
                        print $out ">$sequence\n$hash{$sequence}\n";
                    } 
            }
    }
```

The input file, "Clustered_Barcodes.txt" when opened, looks like the following:

```
    TTTATGC TTTATGG TTTATCC TTTATCG
    TTTATAA TTTATAA TTTATAT TTTATAT TTTATTA
    CTTGTAA
```

There will be three output files from the code, "Clustered_Barcode_1.txt", "Clustered_Barcode_2.txt", and "Clustered_Barcode_3.txt". An example of what the output files would look like could be the 3rd and final file, which would look like the following:

```
    >CTTGTAA 
    ATCGATCGCTTGTAACGATTAGC
```

I need some way to modify my code to identify the number of rows, carrots, or sequences that appear in the file and work that into the title of the file. The new title for the above sequence could be something like "Clustered_Barcode_Number_3_1_Sequence.txt"

PS- I made the hash in the above code manually in attempt to make things simpler. If you want to see the original code, here it is. The input file format is something like:

```
   >TAGCTAGC 
    GCTAAGCGATGCTACGGCTATTAGCTAGCCGGTA
```

Here is the code for setting up the hash:

```
    my $dir = ("~/Documents/Sequences");          
    open(INFILE, "<", "~/Documents/Clustered_Barcodes.txt") or die $!; 

    my %hash = (); 

    my @ArrayofFiles = glob "$dir/*";            #put all files from the specified directory into an array

    #print join("\n", @ArrayofFiles), "\n";       #this is a diagnostic test print statement

    foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){                                 #make hash of barcodes and sequences
        open (my $sequence, $file) or die "can't open file: $!";        
        while (my $line = <$sequence>) {    
            if ($line !~/^>/){ 
                my $seq = $line; 
                $seq =~ s/\R//g;
                #print $seq;           
                $seq =~ m/(CATCAT|TACTAC)([TAGC]{16})([TAGC]+)([TAGC]{16})(CATCAT|TACTAC)/;  
                $hash{$2} = $3;                    
            }
        }
    } 

    while(<INFILE>){
```

etc

Comment: Please check your %hash has duplicate entry. you will not able to handle duplicate entries with your hash structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get the count:

```
my $delimiter = "\t";
my $line = "zyz pqr abc xyz";
my $count = () = $line =~ /$delimiter/g;  # $count is now 3
print $count;
```

Comment: Thank you for an easy, effective answer.

Comment: Why does "$thing = () = .." give you a count? Man, perl is subtle...

Answer (score 1):

Your hash structure is not right for your problem as you have multiple entries for same ids. for example **TTTATAA** hash id has 2 entries in your **%hash**.

To solve this, use **hash of array**  to create the hash.

Change your hash creation code in

```
$hash{$2} = $3;
```

to

```
push(@{$hash{$2}}, $3);
```

Now change your code in the while loop

```
while(my $line = <INFILE>){ 
        chomp $line; 
        open my $out, '>', "Clustered_Barcode_$..txt" or die $!;

        my %id_list;
        foreach my $sequence (split /\t/, $line){
            $id_list{$sequence}=1;

        }
        foreach my $sequence(keys %id_list)
        {
            foreach my $val (@{$hash{$sequence}})
            {
                    print $out ">$sequence\n$val\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I am solving a biological problem that will yield multiple identical keys. I will look into using a hash of array then to create the hash. Thanks.

Comment: If you can tell me how you are creating your **%hash** hash . Then I can help you more properly. are you creating your %hash manually?

Comment: This is part of a much larger set of codes that will generate the hash. For this example (made up for posting the question) I made it manually.

Comment: Long story short, I am doing a regex in a while loop and using the hits of the regex to create the hash.

Comment: large code will not be the problem. Just tell the original format for your input file for your %hash and show the code structure . Because that is the most important part for your problem

Comment: I updated my question. Hopefully that can provide you with the information you are looking for.

Comment: can you please tell  , what will be output file name for TTTATAA and its content  in your final step as you have multiple entry?

Comment: TTTATAA is on the second line in the input file "Clustered_Barcodes.txt". Therefore, it will have the name "Clustered_Barcode_2.txt". I mentioned this earlier. The output is similar to the one previously described, only it will have 5 carrots and 10 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114084/discussion-between-arijit-and-rob).

Comment: When I make your suggested changes, I get the following type of output >TCCTTTTTTTTCATCT
ARRAY(0x203a3b8)
>TATCTTTTTTCATCTC
ARRAY(0x202f870)
>TTTTTTTTTCATCTCC
ARRAY(0x3346df8)
>ATTTTTATTTCATCTC
ARRAY(0x32ea1c8)

Comment: Also, there is no indication of the number of sequences in the file name. The file I just opened has 4 sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I have assummed that;

1. The first digit in the output file **name** is the input file **line number**
2. The second digit in the output file **name** is the input file **column number**
3. That the input hash is a hash of arrays to cover the case of several sequences "matching" the one barcode as mentioned in the comments
4. When a barcode has a match in the hash, that the output file will lists all the sequences in the array, one per line.

The simplest way to do this that I can see is to build the output file using a temporary filename and the rename it when you have all the data.  According to the [perl cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch07_12.htm), the easiest way to create temporary files is with the module [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp).

The key to this solution is to move through the list of barcodes that appear on a line by column index rather than the usual perl way of simply iterating over the list itself.  To get the actual barcodes, the column number `$col` is used to index back into `@barcodes` which is created by splitting the line on whitespace. (Note that [splitting on a single space](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is special cased by perl to emulate the behaviour of one of its predecessors, awk (leading whitespace is removed and the split is on whitespace, not a single space)).

This way we have the column number (indexed from 1) and the line number we can get from [the perl special variable, `$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#SPECIAL-VARIABLES)  We can then use these to rename the file using the builtin, [rename()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);

open(INFILE, "<", "Clustered_Barcodes.txt") or die $!;

my %hash = (
    "TTTATGC" => [ "TATAGCGCTTTATGCTAGCTAGC" ],
    "TTTATGG" => [ "TAGCTAGCTTTATGGGCTAGCTA" ],
    "TTTATCC" => [ "GCTAGCTATTTATCCGCTAGCTA" ],
    "TTTATCG" => [ "AGTCATGCTTTATCGCGATCGAT" ],
    "TTTATAA" => [ "TAGCTAGCTTTATAATAGCTAGC", "ATCGATCGTTTATAACGATCGAT" ],
    "TTTATAT" => [ "TCGATCGATTTATATTAGCTAGC", "TAGCTAGCTTTATATGCTAGCTA" ],
    "TTTATTA" => [ "GCTAGCTATTTATTATAGCTAGC" ],
    "CTTGTAA" => [ "ATCGATCGCTTGTAACGATTAGC" ]
);

my $cbn = "Clustered_Barcode_Number";
my $trailer = "Sequence.txt";

while (my $line = <INFILE>) {
    chomp $line ;
    my $line_num = $. ;

    my @barcodes = split " ", $line ;
    for my $col ( 1 .. @barcodes )  {
        my $barcode = $barcodes[ $col - 1 ];  # arrays indexed from 0

        # skip this one if its not in the hash
        next unless exists $hash{$barcode} ;
        my @sequences =  @{ $hash{$barcode} } ;

        # Have a hit - create temp file and output sequences
        my ($out, $temp_filename) = tempfile();
        say $out ">$barcode" ;
        say $out $_ for (@sequences) ;
        close $out ;

        # Rename based on input line and column
        my $new_name = join "_", $cbn, $line_num, $col, $trailer  ;
        rename ($temp_filename, $new_name) or
            warn "Couldn't rename $temp_filename to $new_name: $!\n" ;
    }
}
close INFILE
```

All of the barcodes in your sample input data have a match in the hash, so when I run this, I get 4 files for line 1, 5 for line 2 and 1 for line 3.

```
Clustered_Barcode_Number_1_1_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_1_2_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_1_3_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_1_4_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_1_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_2_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_3_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_4_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_5_Sequence.txt
Clustered_Barcode_Number_3_1_Sequence.txt
```

`Clustered_Barcode_Number_1_2_Sequence.txt` for example has:

```
>TTTATGG
TAGCTAGCTTTATGGGCTAGCTA
```

and `Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_5_Sequence.txt` has:

```
>TTTATTA
GCTAGCTATTTATTATAGCTAGC
```

`Clustered_Barcode_Number_2_3_Sequence.txt` - which matched a hash key with two sequences - had the following;

```
>TTTATAT
TCGATCGATTTATATTAGCTAGC
TAGCTAGCTTTATATGCTAGCTA
```

I was speculating here about what you wanted when a supplied barcode had two matches.  Hope that helps.